# Defining '999e999' value without using char type in C++

Tags: c++

Is it possible to define `999e999` value without using the `char` type?

I've tried defining it even with `unsigned long long`, but the compiler keeps giving me `constant too big` error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be interested in [GMP](https://gmplib.org).

Comment: Yes that's the way to go hypnokat, just like @JesperJuhl mentioned. However, I suggest you make sure first that you *really* need to use that big numbers!

Comment: based on what you want to do with your number, you may be able to use openssl `BN` functions too.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would one ever need such a big number? Even if you think that every particle in the universe is itself a universe with the same number of particles, you'll have about 10^172 particles in total. Even if you wanted to count the number of particles that can fit in these universes "space", that number would still be huge! Do you need unit precision on such a... supercalifragilistic number?

Comment: It is just a random experiment I thought of, I'm a programming newbie. Still, thanks to that random thought, even thought I can't do that in C++ alone, I now know about the existance of GMP, so I'm still walking out with something new :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to define `999e999` value without using the char type?

No, that's not possible using intrinsic c++ data types. That's a way to big number that could be held in either a `unsigned long long` type in c++.

A `long double` type would enable you to use 10 based exponents as large as you want, for modern FPU architectures.

What can be achieved with your current CPU architecture can be explored using the [`std::numeric_limits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) facilities like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {   
   std::cout<< "max_exponent10: " << std::numeric_limits<long double>::max_exponent10  << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
max_exponent10: 4932
```

See the [online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/652a1733413070aa)

You have to use a 3rd party library (like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)) or write your own algorithms to deal with big numbers like that.

Comment: Actually, where `long double` has a bigger size than the usual 8-byte `double` (like 80-bit on x86), `long double` can  store `999e999`.

Comment: On x86, FPU supports 80-bit numbers. And it is usually accessible by using `long double`. This type still can be used today on x86_64 as well.

Comment: @geza Reference please (including support from c++ standards)?

Comment: What do you mean by support from C++ standards? C++ standard doesn't say too much about the range of floating point. It doesn't change the fact, that on x86, the FPU (i387) can use 80-bit numbers. With GCC/Clang, this is definitely accessible by using `long double`. See: https://godbolt.org/z/e0HD_T (TBYTE means a 10-byte type)

Comment: @geza [M'kay](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/361eba862f2353d5). I probably should refine my answer.

Comment: I don't want to nitpick :) But this 80-bit support is quite old. The original 8087 supported it, around ~1980. It's actually the contrary today: SSE doesn't support it. And MSVC dropped the support as I've now checked (I didn't know this). I don't know which MSVC version was the last which supported it.

Comment: @geza Looks fine though with my online sample.

Comment: Yep, because you've used GCC. GCC still supports 80-bit float, it uses FPU for `long double`. For all the other types, it uses SSE by default. So, when you mix `long double` with `double`/`float`, it has to move data between these two units (through memory).

Comment: @geza Sure, I got that difference :3

Comment: Phew, that was hard to find: https://web.archive.org/web/20010418053656/http://support.microsoft.com/support/kb/articles/Q129/2/09.asp. And I've checked Visual C++ compilers, the last which supported 80-bit long doubles, was Visual C++ 1.5 (in 1993, way back before Visual Studio existed).

Answer (score 2):

In most (If not all) implementations, that constant is just too big to be represented as a `unsigned long long` or `long double` (Though some may just have it be floating point infinity).

You may instead be interested in [`std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity) (for `float`, `double` or `long double`) or [`std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) instead.

Comment: I've looked through your example, but if I read it correctly then maximum value for `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` is `1.79769e+308`, which is a lot less than `999e999`, so I'm afraid I wouldn't be able to use it. Even so, could I use `std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity()` to extract a value other than infinity?

Comment: @hypnokat It boils down to how floats are implemented in the system. [The most common implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) has a largest value (Which is what `max` returns) and an `inf` value (Which is what `infinity` returns). These, again, depend on how the float types are implemented.

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried defining it even with unsigned long long, but the compiler keeps giving me constant too big error.

Of course it does. A `long long` is typically 64 bits long, which gives you `log(2^64) ≅ 19` decimal digits of precision. `999e999 ≅ (10^3)^1000`, so is on the order of 3000 decimal digits long, or nearly 10,000 bits long. So `999e999` isn't just too big for a `long long`, it's too big by an enormous margin.

> Is it possible to define 999e999 value without using the char type?

Sure. You could define an integer-like type based on an array of some sort of integers, like `long long`. You'd still need to write a set of operators to work with your new giant type, though. Also, most of the time when you're working with numbers that large, you don't need an exact representation, which is why floating point types like `float` and `double` are useful.

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking obvious stuff, but by defining an integer-like type do you mean I could use `typedef`? If so then how do I write my own operators from that point on?

Comment: Sure, you could define a type like `typedef long[350] ReallyBigNumber;` and then define a bunch of functions that add, subtract, multiply, etc. values of that type. If you're working in C++, you might want to create `ReallyBigNumber` as a class, and then you can overload `operator+`, `operator-`, etc. so that you can use normal math operators like `+` and `-`. But it'd be a little silly to do all that when arbitrary precision libraries like [GMP](https://gmplib.org) already exist.

Comment: @SolomonSlow You're right: `999e999` is scientific notation, so should be interpreted as `999*10^999`; I was thinking of 999^999, and I probably still didn't get it quite right. In a hurry just now, but will fix in a few hours.